# HTML report output window/dialogue

Tags: javascript, html, xpages

On my xPage I have a button that generates some output/report (SSJS).
Is there a way to open a new modal or float window and put that output into it. It's gonna be a small window to show the report results. But report is gonna be a huge like few megabits. Assume it's not good idea to put the output in some scope variable line by line and then bind it to a field in new window. Any feasible solution?

Comment: "small (modal) window" + "huge like few megabits" = serious problem

Comment: OK Mr. Kossuth... What is the best practice to do such action? I need to generate some application report and represent it to users in either same web-page or in txt file or in email message

Comment: I vote for Paul Stephen Withers's answer - open it to new window. User can hit CTRL+S to save it. Or use proper content-type to raise save dialog in browser automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably worth using CSJS to call `window.open()` and open a new XPage (which would effectively be an XAgent), although that will be prevented by popup blockers. Make sure to set `viewState="nostate"` on the XAgent XPage though, to avoid serializing a component tree for it.

Comment: The report is gonna be generated by SSJS.. And it's gonna be few pages of text I want to show either in current or new window.. (just the report text). Not sure if it can work with CSJS

Comment: The CSJS will be needed to launch a new browser window or dialog (a SSJS approach will still trigger `view.postScript` to launch a dialog on the browser. The page displayed (in new page or as a different URL loaded into a dialog) would still be SSJS.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `window.open()` you could consider using a dojo [content pane](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/layout/ContentPane.html). This will avoid potential issues with popup blockers.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `<xe:dialog>` tag from the Extension Library, the Dialog control, and you might include the Dialog Content control. You can load its content when opening the dialog box. The dialog is started using XSP.openDialog(...)

As for the megabytes report: where is it stored? In rich text field in a document?

Comment: the report is gonna be generated on fly by SSJS.. Then I want to show this text in blank window.. Like plain text